# OC4J 10.1.3 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, oc4j

I am getting OutOfMemoryError while trying to deploy a War file on OC4J 10.1.3 on Win XP 32-bit OS (4GB) machine. The same configuration of OC4J 10.1.3 on Sun Solaris the war file is getting deployed properly.

I did tried the recommendation provided on the below link:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/616067

However was not able to fix the issue. Could someone give more recommendations on this issue please ?

The oc4j_opmn.xml is this:

```
<ias-component id="OC4J">
    <process-type id="home" module-id="OC4J" status="enabled">
      <module-data>
  <category id="start-parameters">
          <data id="java-options" value="-server -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -ms512M -mx1024M -XX:AppendRatio=3 -Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/home/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false"/>
        </category>
        <category id="stop-parameters">
          <data id="java-options" value="-Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/home/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false"/>
        </category>
      </module-data>
      <start   timeout="600" retry="2"/> 
      <stop    timeout="120"/>
      <restart timeout="720" retry="2"/>
      <port id="default-web-site" range="12501-12600" protocol="ajp"/>
      <port id="rmi" range="12401-12500"/>
      <port id="jms" range="12601-12700"/>
      <process-set id="default_group" numprocs="1"/>
    </process-type>
</ias-component>
```

Web console deployment log:

```
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Application Deployer for xxx STARTS. 
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Copy the archive to D:\product\10.1.3\OracleAS_2\j2ee\home\applications\xxx.ear
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Initialize D:\product\10.1.3\OracleAS_2\j2ee\home\applications\xxx.ear begins...
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Unpacking xxx.ear
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Done unpacking xxx.ear
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:32 PM] Unpacking xxx.war
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Done unpacking xxx.war
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initialize D:\product\10.1.3\OracleAS_2\j2ee\home\applications\xxx.ear ends...
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Starting application : xxx
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initializing ClassLoader(s)
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initializing EJB container
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Loading connector(s)
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Starting up resource adapters
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initializing EJB sessions
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Committing ClassLoader(s)
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initialize xxx begins...
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Initialize xxx ends...
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Started application : xxx
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Binding web application(s) to site default-web-site begins...
[Feb 23, 2015 5:52:33 PM] Binding xxx web-module for application xxx to site default-web-site under context root xxx
```

Error log:

```
15/02/23 15:14:23.817 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:14:28.98 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:19:56.511 ascontrol: Servlet error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
15/02/23 15:21:59.982 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:22:03.341 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:41:55.911 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Stopped
15/02/23 15:42:05.755 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:42:09.255 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 15:44:42.461 ascontrol: Servlet error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
15/02/23 15:44:51.602 ascontrol: Servlet error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
15/02/23 16:29:16.453 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 16:29:20.749 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 17:51:01.600 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Stopped
15/02/23 17:51:08.679 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 17:51:12.101 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/23 17:53:11.978 ascontrol: Servlet error
15/02/23 17:53:12.962 ascontrol: Servlet error
15/02/23 17:53:24.166 ascontrol: Servlet error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Really appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Well, 1GB on a 32bit windows machine might just not be enough.  What arguments did you add or change on the web container to which you are deploying?   If you modified JAVA_OPTS, did you restart the container afterwards?  For more info start jconsole and aim it at the oc4j process - gives nice views of the memory used.

Comment: This is the earlier java start parameters:
        <category id="start-parameters">
          <data id="java-options" value="-Xrs -server -Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/home/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false"/>
        </category>

Modifications is to add the memory params:
<category id="start-parameters">
     <data id="java-options" value="-server -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -ms512M -mx1024M -XX:AppendRatio=3 -Djava.security.policy=$ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/home/config/java2.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.webdir.enable=false"/>
        </category>

Comment: Yes, I did restart couple of times after making the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` usually indicates the program you are trying to run requires more RAM than you are allocating to it. Try inceasing the `XX:MaxPermSize=128M` to something like large like `XX:MaxPermSize=1G` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know if increasing the size to 1G works.

Comment: Making to 1G not helping. Still getting OOM.


15/02/24 09:30:41.751 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Stopped
15/02/24 09:31:04.142 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/24 09:31:07.439 ascontrol: 10.1.3.0.0 Started
15/02/24 09:33:39.145 ascontrol: Servlet error
15/02/24 09:33:41.130 ascontrol: Servlet error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space



I seriously doubt if there is any other setup need to be changed or configured in OC4J 10.1.3.